# TableLayout cutting off text

Tags: android, layout, text, tablelayout

I am very beginner in android development and I've been googling a lot about this problem I have with no success. My activity have a tablelayout with 3 lines and 2 columns. Turns out when I use android:scretchColumns="1" so the table can fill all the screen width part of the second column is being cutted off. I've set layout_gravity="right" for the second column as I designed to be. Here is layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:stretchColumns="1">


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total"
            android:text="@string/total" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_value"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
        />


    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qty_participant"
            android:text="@string/qty_participant" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/qty_participant_value"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>


    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/participant_share"
            android:text="@string/participant_share"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/participant_share_value"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />


    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    </TableLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was passing android:stretchColumns parameter wrongly. It was stretching only the first colum. Using android:stretchColumns="*" and removing View.. beteween TableRows solved the problem